# What is the correct / legal procedure to obtain permission to install Android Market or Google Play on a system that's in development?

Tags: android

I am an Android OS developer.  I have a tablet in development that I'm in the process porting Android ICS to.  Now I want to install Android Market or Google Play.  This system is under development, not distributed and not licenses / approved by Google yet.

I see plenty of Q & A about how to install Android Market on an emulator.  I'm pretty sure I can use that same procedure to install Android Market on my development system.  But that's not my question exactly.

I have a hunch, and I can see others have speculated as much, that installing (side-loading) Android Market without Google's permission is not legal.  My question is, as a developer, how do I apply for or obtain or get approval from Google to download and install Android Market or Google Play on my development system?  Believe me, I've searched around the Android development website aplenty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> installing (side-loading) Android Market without Google's permission is not legal

Correct.

> how do I apply for or obtain or get approval from Google to download and install Android Market or Google Play on my development system?

Quoting [the documentation](http://source.android.com/faqs.html#compatibility): "Google Play is only licensed to handset manufacturers shipping devices. For questions about specific cases, contact android-partnerships@google.com".

Comment: OK Thx a lot.  I'll add that when I sent an e-mail to that address I got an auto-reply with a link to a website for filling out a partnership form.  I guess the worst they could do is say no.

Comment: @JoeC: Yeah, I have no sense as to what size firm they are willing to work with. Each device consumes some quantity of Google engineering time to confirm compliance, so they probably have some limits as to what they will entertain. Best o' luck!

Comment: I've tried contacting them several times to license 5,000 devices, I guess they are not interested in responding. I had to license SlideMe as a app store replacement. It was cheap compared to what some manufacturers were telling me about the Google license

Answer (score 0):

I am also developing a tablet, got the same form but no response from Google, I'm interested in hearing if you got any.

What is happening right now, I decided to implement Slide Me as the end user app store, it is possible to brand it with your name and icon.

It works well on my test devices so I recommend it if you're just looking for a market application, give it a try.

Though, there are a whole lot more markets (and cheaper one too) out there.